# Filtering out specific Python logging messages

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to prevent specific messages from being written to a 
Django logfile?  I've read the Django logger docs and they only address
filtering errors for a Django class.

The error I want to prevent from being written to my logfile is this:

```
[19/Dec/2014 12:21:21] INFO [requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:171] Starting new HTTP connection (1): api.wurflcloud.com
```

My Django logging configuration is shown below.

Thanks

```
# settings.py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'logfile': {
            'level':LOG_LEVEL,
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/myproj/myproj.log',
            'maxBytes': 50000,
            'backupCount': 2,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'database_logfile': {
            'level':LOG_LEVEL,
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/myproj/database.log',
            'maxBytes': 50000,
            'backupCount': 2,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'console':{
            'level':LOG_LEVEL,
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
            # Only send emails when DEBUG = False
            #'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'WARN',
        },
        'django.request': {
           'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
           'level': 'ERROR',
           'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['database_logfile'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'logfile', 'mail_admins'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: why can't you just filter by logging level?

Comment: Because I don't want to filter all INFO-level messages, just this particular one.

Comment: Then you should probably have a look at the [logging docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#filter-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python `logging` package does not support filtering by the message content, only by message logger and message level.

Two potential ways to solve the problem are

- Monkey-patch the violating function and replace it with your own version which doesn't produce the given message (function at `requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool`:171)
- Write your own logging handler which can handle filtering log messages by their content (very heavy handed approach just to get rid of one message)

Also as the long term solution you can try

- Communicate the `requests` package community, explain your issue, seek co-operation and write the patch to fix the library, so that in the future versions one can get rid of the particular message easily

Comment: Thanks Mikko.  From my reading of the Python and Django logging docs, I suspected this was the case but wanted to get confirmation from someone more experienced.  One other option I thought of is just to do post-processing on my logs to filter out this and other messages I don't care about.